# How to create a table by iterating words in sentence in python?

Tags: python, nltk, text-processing

For the example given below, I would like to create a table for the list of 'Directors' and 'Stars'. The idea is to iterate the sentences, detect words which exist between word 'Director:' and 'Stars:' and put into respective cells.

The sentence.

```
Director:
Peter
Jackson,
John
Marsh
Stars:
Elijah
Wood,
Ian
McKellen,
Orlando
Bloom,
Sean
Bean
```

Full list of words
https://justpaste.it/3qjc4

Table to create

| Director | Stars |
| --- | --- |
| Peter Jackson | Elijah Wood |
| John Marsh | Ian McKellen |
|  | Orlando Bloom |
|  | Sean Bean |

Comment: Where is your data saved? Is it a txt file? And what have you tried so far in order to implement your idea, which looks correct?

Comment: it is in text file. it just a list of words that I have iterated from a sentences. So far I have tried using simple if else statement but yet to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

l=[]
with open('yourtxtfile.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        l.append(i)

l=[i.replace('\n', '') for i in l]

Director=l[1:l.index('Stars')]
Stars=l[l.index('Stars')+1:]

for i in range(len(Director)-len(Stars)):
    Director.append('')

df=pd.DataFrame({'Director':Director, 'Stars':Stars})
```

Comment: apparently is says AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'